# Как с помощью Flexbox расположить так элементы без обертки?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Пример]

Сейчас использую такой способ:

```
<div class="logo">
  <img class="avatar" src="...">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="title">...</p>
    <p class="subtitle">...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Т.е. класс `text` служит оберткой для `title` и `subtitle`. Обертка располагается справа от изображения, а потом уже внутри неё идут два блока текста друг за другом вертикально.

Возник вопрос: можно ли как-то используя auto margins, `align-self` и тому подобные полезные штуки, как-то относящиеся к флексбоксу, сделать то же самое, но только без обертки?

Не используя абсолютное позиционирование и другие техники.

Спасибо.

Comment: как понять без обёртки ? у вас же есть элемент серого цвета !

Comment: @Максим Ленский , имеется в виду обёртка для `.title` и `.subtitle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно колончатым флексом, но там свои пляски с высотой, поэтому лучше с обёрткой.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
p{
  margin:0;
}
.logo{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-content:flex-start;
  height:100px;
}
.avatar{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#acd;
  margin:0 15px 0 0;
}
.title,.subtitle{
  border:1px solid;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background-color:#cda;
  width:calc(100% - 115px);
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img class="avatar" src="...">
  <p class="title">...</p>
  <p class="subtitle">...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете красиво и универсально сделать на гридах, с каким-нибудь ограниченным фоллбеком на флексбоксе (код флексбокса из соседнего примера).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.logo {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.avatar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.title,
.subtitle {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  grid-column: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

@supports not (display: grid) {
  .logo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: flex-start;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .avatar {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  }
  .title,
  .subtitle {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 115px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img class="avatar" src="...">
  <p class="title">Title</p>
  <p class="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
</div>
```

Comment: В директиву `@supports` лучше заносить как раз таки стили с `grid`, т.к. браузеры поддерживающие `css grid` наверняка поддерживают `@supports`,  а наоборот - не факт. Пример IE10: гриды не поддерживает, флексы в `@supports` не видит, хотя их и поддерживает.

Comment: Можно и так, как вы описали, всё зависит от подхода. Детектить гриды можно не только через `@supports`, хоть это и более адекватный подход )